# Selective mail message merge

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do a merge and embed some logic: I'm sending instructions to a list of recipients, and only include parts of the message which apply to each recipient. The data is populating from an excel table with a column of user names/email address, and columns with flag variables for each user designating whether or not they should receive a paragraph of instructions identified by the column. I don't know VB very well, and I'd like to use those flag variables to designate whether or not the instructions corresponding to that column should be included in the message or not.

Please let me know if this is even feasible in VBA, or if there's a better way of going about this--currently the list of recipients for instructions is small, but it is expected to grow quickly, and I would like to develop this process before that happens.

Update: I should add: *how* should I go about doing this? What resources would be helpful-guides, pastebin, etc.?

Comment: To answer your question, this is very feasible in VBA.

Comment: Thanks! I should have been more clear: please see update. I don't know VBA, and more details would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do a google search for `EXCEL VBA For Each Loop` `EXCEL VBA AutoFilter`, `EXCEL VBA Range Offset` ... that will give a good start. Also, try writing out the logic in psuedo-code (English version of what you want the code to do), then translate it to actual code.

Comment: Did you check this?
http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/word-help/use-mail-merge-to-send-personalized-e-mail-messages-to-your-e-mail-address-list-HA010109162.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include a paragraph for a particular recipient, you can set the text for that field in the excel table to blank (i.e. =""). The mail merge field will still be there in the template letter, but it won't correspond to any visible text and it won't take up any space. If a paragraph is too long to fit into a single excel cell, you can split it into smaller pieces.

You can do this without resorting to VBA by having a column in your excel table for each paragraph you might want to include. These can in turn be populated with the paragraph text, or blanked out, via a vlookup or if function, based on the flag columns.